# jemalloc and concurrent hash map

Tags: malloc

I have huge `concurrent hash map ( ACE )` , when I am saying huge , I am doing lots and lots of `put` and `get` operation. This is on `windows` platform. Recently I was reading about `jemalloc` ,

For the above scenario If I use `jemalloc`, will it help me in performance and avoid memory fragmentation.